# prcomp error: "undefined columns selected"

Tags: r, matrix, pca, prcomp

I am trying to build a PCA with a matrix of labeled numeric data. I am trying to select only certain columns (6-78) to include in the PCA, but have an error (syntax?)

Here's the code:

```
cytokines.pca <- prcomp(PICHCytokines[,c(6:78)], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
summary(cytokines.pca)
```

The error is:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , c(6:78)) : undefined columns selected

Here's the structure of my data frame:

```
str(PICHCytokines)
'data.frame':   106 obs. of  69 variables:
 $ Record.ID        : Factor w/ 106 levels "FA001","FA007",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Record ID"
 $ Event.Name       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Enrollment and Admission",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Event Name"
 $ Time.since.trauma: 'labelled' num  0.717 7.717 1.383 0.817 2.85 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Time since trauma"
 $ Batch.Number     : 'labelled' int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Batch Number"
 $ Plate.Number     : 'labelled' int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Plate Number"
 $ FASL.MFI         : 'labelled' num  748 295 256 333 275 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "FASL MFI"
 $ TGFA.MFI         : 'labelled' num  122 64.2 96 126 94.8 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "TGFA MFI"
 $ MIP1A.MFI        : 'labelled' num  1611 142 158 339 168 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "MIP1A MFI"
 $ IL27.MFI         : 'labelled' num  139.2 40 63 52.5 63.2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "IL27 MFI"
 $ IL1B.MFI         : 'labelled' num  68 38.2 77.5 46 70.8 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "IL1B MFI"
 $ IL2.MFI          : 'labelled' num  159 61.5 120.8 79.5 117.2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "IL2 MFI"
```

Comment: 'data.frame':   106 obs. of  69 variables your data.frame has only 69 columns, how to you take up to 78?

Comment: Yes! I finally caught that and fixed it. Thank you!!